# How to hide +/- button in vue js with special condition

Tags: html, css, vue.js

How can I hide the `+/-` button when there is no item at below?

Current Problem

[image: Current Problem]

[Example Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exampleoftreeview-h3ofpo)

```html
<template v-for="item in SevenLengthlist" :key="item">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="item-0" /><label for="item-0">{{ item.mAcName }} --- {{ item.mName }}</label>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="item2 in item.TenLength" :key="item2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="item-0-0" />
          <label for="item-0-0">{{ item2.mAcName }} --- {{ item2.mName }}</label>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="item3 in item2.TenLength" :key="item3">
              <input type="checkbox" id="item-0-0" />
              <label for="item-0-0">{{ item3.mAcName }} --- {{ item3.mName }}</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: You could use `v-if`. Doesn't it do the job ?

Comment: @Alexis I am still think like, how item2 check item3 exist or not..

Comment: I'd say using `v-if="item2.TenLength.length"` on your `input checkbox`

Comment: I've looked at the CSS styling, it seems like you probably want to use a [v-bind css](https://www.jsnow.io/p/javascript/vue/vue-dynamic-css) method

Comment: You're pretty much there already. Do you mind creating a real [repro] so that we could help efficiently?

Comment: @kissu hi I create an example https://codesandbox.io/s/exampleoftreeview-h3ofpo     From the link you can see the checkbox is still there when there is not more item. So what is i want when there is not more item and the checkbox be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your current implementation is quite bad.
Doing that with an image + background offset is not a good way of doing things here (SVG + `v-show` would be far better/easier to handle).

Some key points:

- the result will be sub-par, you'll have pixelisation if zoomed
- the logic needs to be brought to the template (I do not recommend
  trying to do all of that into the style section even if somehow feasible, no point: use what Vue provides you)
- your example is naive and doesn't use recursivity at all (while it's the main thing here)
- I fixed quite few mistakes regarding proper practices + console errors (please use ESlint)

---

I recommend the following example from the docs: https://vuejs.org/examples/#tree

---

Meanwhile, the final result can be achieved by using the following code

```html
<template>
  <div class="css-treeview">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in list1" :key="item.a">
        <input :id="`item-${item.a}`" type="checkbox" />
        <label :for="`item-${item.a}`"
          :class="[!item.list2.length && 'hide-when-not-needed', item.list2.length && 'open-if-possible']">
          {{ item.a }}
        </label>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item2 in item.list2" :key="item2.a">
            <input :id="`item-${item2.a}`" type="checkbox" />
            <label :for="`item-${item2.a}`"
              :class="[!item2?.list3?.length && 'hide-when-not-needed', item2?.list3?.length && 'open-if-possible']">
              {{ item2.a }}
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      list1: [
        {
          a: 'Alex',
          list2: [{ a: 'Dog' }],
        },
        {
          a: 'Blex',
          list2: [{ a: 'Dogoo' }],
        },
        {
          a: 'Clex',
          list2: [],
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.css-treeview ul,
.css-treeview li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.css-treeview input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.css-treeview {
  font: normal 11px 'Segoe UI', Arial, Sans-serif;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.css-treeview a {
  color: #00f;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.css-treeview a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.css-treeview input+label+ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 22px;
}

.css-treeview input+label+ul {
  display: none;
}

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview label::before {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.css-treeview input:disabled+label {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.css-treeview input:checked:not(:disabled)+label+ul {
  display: block;
}

/* this part is interesting */
.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview label::before {
  background: url('http://experiments.wemakesites.net/pages/css3-treeview/example/icons.png') no-repeat;
}

.css-treeview label,
.css-treeview a,
.css-treeview label::before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.css-treeview label {
  background-position: 18px 0;
}

.css-treeview label::before {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  margin: 0 22px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-position: 0 -32px;
}

/* this is the fix */
label.hide-when-not-needed::before {
  background-position: 0 -48px;
}

/* this one is bad */
input:checked+label.open-if-possible::before {
  background-position: 0 -16px;
}

/* webkit adjacent element selector bugfix */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  .css-treeview {
    -webkit-animation: webkit-adjacent-element-selector-bugfix infinite 1s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes webkit-adjacent-element-selector-bugfix {
    from {
      padding: 0;
    }

    to {
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Here is [a playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).